# How to define AWS GLUE schema for JSON sent from python SDK to firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have this setup in mind:

*PythonSDK sending predefined JSON -> aws kinesis firehose -> convert data to "Parquet" using AWS GLUE schema -> save data to S3 (either if succeed or not).*

While sending primities type like strings, ints & booleans is easy, sending array/struct isn't trivial at all.
I keep getting weird error messages of:

> The schema is invalid. Error parsing the schema: Error: type expected
> at the position 0 of 'STRUCTname:STRING,id:BIGINT,is_bla:BOOLEAN'
> but 'STRUCT' is found.

OR

> The schema is invalid. Error parsing the schema: Error: type expected
> at the position 0 of 'ARRAY' but 'ARRAY' is found.

1. Why I'm getting those error messages?
2. Is there a proper doc/examples for schema data types?
   i could only find [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-Column) saying Column `Type` should match the "[Single-line string pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-common.html#aws-glue-api-regex-oneLine)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my question:

there is some delay between saving GLUE schema & sending data to firehose. updated JSONs I send used old schema hence the errors.

also from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385005/dataformatconversion-invalidschema-using-hyphen-dash-in-aws-glue-and-firehose?rq=1) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950945/put-map-data-via-firehose-to-athena?rq=1) we have to validate some naming conventions ourselfs, it's quite unfortunate AWS doesn't do it upon creation.